# Livewire validate nested component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a form on my `TimesheetPaymentForm` component. However I'd like to use a nested component `ChecksForm` inside the form

```
<x-cards.body>   
    <x-forms.row 
        wire: model="user.full_name"
        errorName="user.full_name"
        name="user.full_name" 
        text="Payee"
        type="text"  
        disabled
        >
    </x-forms.row>
   
    @livewire('checks.checks-form')
</x-cards.body>
```

Checks-form only has check-specific inputs and I don't want to use @include since I would have to duplicate the data and validation each time I use this in my app.
The data from the `ChecksForm` component is loading as expected in the `TimesheetPaymentForm`. However, since this data is nested in the main component, when it validates those on the `TimesheetPaymentForm` and I get an error saying the input is not in the rules to be valiaded.